# is this a bug in anytime's anydate function?

Tags: r, anytime

I'm trying to convert a vector of dates and this is the minimal reproducible example.

```
dates <- c("04-Nov-2013", "20-Jan-2014", "28-Jan-2014", "24-Apr-2014")
library(anytime)
anydate(dates)
```

My output is:

```
[1] "2013-11-04"  NA  NA  "2014-04-24"
```

which is incorrect for the middle two elements.  Is this a bug? My version of anytime package is 0.1.1

sessionInfo() as requested:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] anytime_0.1.1   lazyeval_0.2.0  magrittr_1.5    lubridate_1.6.0
[5] readr_1.0.0     stringr_1.1.0   dplyr_0.5.0     tidyr_0.6.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.5-1      tools_3.3.2    tibble_1.2    
[6] Rcpp_0.12.8    stringi_1.1.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot replicate that:

```
R> dates <- c("04-Nov-2013", "20-Jan-2014", "28-Jan-2014", "24-Apr-2014")
R> anydate(dates)
[1] "2013-11-04" "2014-01-20" "2014-01-28" "2014-04-24"
R>
```

We did have one weird recent bug on Windows64 with this `%b` format.  What platform are you on?

That discussion is in [this issue ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/33) and make sure you follow to the end.  I did change some code, so you may need that update -- which should go into a new version "Real Soon Now".  But as far as I know the bug only bites in Windows 64 bit, and not even Windows 32 bit.

Comment: FWIW it works fine on my systems (macOS Sierra/Ubuntu) as well.

Comment: @hackR: Please try [this link](https://artifacts.r-hub.io/anytime_0.1.1.1.tar.gz-ef80f4fa19334dedbdfc78ffc698d27d/) for a version freshly built off the current repo, thanks to [RHub](http://builder.r-hub.io).  Let us know how that one fares.

Comment: Hi Dirk.  Woo hoo! that fixed it.  Thank you so much for the super-speedy responses and fix.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept then.  And I take this as vote number two that the fix should go to CRAN...

Comment: I upvoted and accepted.  it gets my vote.  Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped.  We are more likely to see all bug reports at the repo, but I now follow the [tag:anytime] tag as well.